# Using a RegEx to split a string to store the substring within delimiter in a map to create Key Value pairs

Tags: arrays, regex, dictionary, go, hashmap

In Go-Lang

I need to extract from a string a substring which sits in between two delimiters, each pair of delimiter will be a key and the substring will be it's value.

A Quick Example: "Coca Cola is refreshing < pepsi > is simply < not >"

The Two delimiters: < and >

Target: extractedMap:= map[string]string{"first":"pepsi", "second":"not"}

The regex expression I've tried to capture the data between the two

```
\<(.*?)\>
```

How can each substring extracted be stored in a map, that can be iterated through to store the extracted substrings

Comment: Just some thoughts. The best way may not be to use a regex, so you may need to rephrase the question without assumptions about the answer.  Also why not just return a slice instead of a map?

Comment: Welcome to SO @Bionic_Titan. From next time, please share whatever you have tried to do get this done. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on asking questions. I will leave an answer for your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go does not have a direct method to find all matches and return it as a map. You can use a [FindAllStringSubmatch](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch) from regexp package to get all matches and range over it. Here is an example

```
str := "Coca Cola is refreshing < pepsi > is simply < not >"
r := regexp.MustCompile(`\<(.*?)\>`)

matches := r.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1)
for _, match := range matches {
    if len(match) > 1 {
        fmt.Println("Found match: ", match[1])
    }
}

// Output
// Found match:   pepsi
// Found match:   not
```

Comment: in playground ,https://play.golang.org/p/Ci13DR0CPIC

Comment: If we add to the original sentence "Coca Cola is refreshing < pepsi > is simply < not >":alphabet
Is there an addition we can make to the regEx to include everything after the : to capture it once we finish the first operation?